# Character pointers pointing to character array instead of assigning

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm preparing a program to read a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLEN 256

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE *fp;    
    char currLine[MAXLEN];

    char **fileLines = malloc(MAXLEN * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++) {
        fileLines[i] = malloc(MAXLEN * sizeof(char));
    }

    int lineCounter = 0;

    fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(currLine, sizeof(currLine), fp)) {
    fileLines[lineCounter] = currLine;
        printf("%s", fileLines[lineCounter]);
        lineCounter++;
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < lineCounter; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", fileLines[i]);
    }

    /*for (int i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++) {
        free(fileLines[i]);
    }*/
    free(fileLines);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Within the while loop, I read a line of file from the text file `sample.txt`:

```
first line
2nd
linea tres
#4
```

And attempt to assign the character array to one of the character pointers from the double pointer, then print. At that moment, printing happens correctly, but once outside of the loop, I print each item again, and they all print the last element:

OUTPUT:

```
first line
2nd
linea tres
#4

#4
#4
#4
#4
```

From this, my suspicion is that what the "assignment" is actually doing is pointing towards the local variable `currline`, whose last value is `#4`. So how could I correctly assign the line read instead of pointing to the character array? Thanks for any help in advice

Comment: Suspect OP was get seg fault when the commented code `/*for (int i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++)...` was uncommented.

Comment: The run failed then, but all the output showed

Comment: "instead of assigning"? Arrays are not assignable in C. You want to copy the data from one array to another - use a library function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop where you read the file, you must strip the trailing linefeed and copy the contents of each line read into the array.  You currently store a pointer to the line buffer for each line read.  All lines in the string array point to the same buffer, which at best holds the last line read from the file.

Here is an improved version of this loop:

```
while (lineCounter < MAXLEN && fgets(currLine, sizeof(currLine), fp)) {
    currLine[strcspn(currLine, "\n")] = '\0';
    strcpy(fileLines[lineCounter], currLine);
    printf("%s\n", fileLines[lineCounter]);  // debug
    lineCounter++;
}
```

This mistake also explains why you could nor free the lines in the `fileLines` array.  These pointers no longer pointed to allocated space, invoking undefined behavior when passed to `free()`.

Note that instead of pre-allocating a full array of lines, you could allocate the exact space for each line read from the file this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLEN 256

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char currLine[MAXLEN];
    char **fileLines = malloc(MAXLEN * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXLEN; i++) {
        fileLines[i] = NULL;
    }

    int lineCounter = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;

    while (lineCounter < MAXLEN && fgets(currLine, sizeof(currLine), fp)) {
        currLine[strcspn(currLine, "\n")] = '\0';
        fileLines[lineCounter] = strdup(currLine);
        lineCounter++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < lineCounter; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", fileLines[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lineCounter; i++) {
        free(fileLines[i]);
    }
    free(fileLines);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting every pointer in `fileLines[lineCounter]` to point to the same string which is `CurrentLine`, so at the end of execution, they should all print the last string stored in `CurrentLine`.

To solve this problem, you need to copy `CurrentLine` content (at each iteration) into the memory allocated for `fileLines[lineCounter]` & already assigned a pointer to it by `malloc`, for instance, you can use: 
 `strncpy(fileLines[lineCounter], CurrentLine, strlen(CurrentLine))`

Comment: Don't forget to use `malloc` in the sake of allocating memory to the line to be copied from `CurrentLine`.